# How to Update the Canvas with invalidate

Tags: android, android-custom-view, curve

This might be a long post, but I'll try to make it as simple as possible.  I'm trying to curve a line using `onDraw()` but I'm having trouble with it.  I've been told to just invalidate the canvas and it should work, but to no avail.  (For reference I'll put an image at the bottom of the current design). Once again, I'm sorry that it's a long post but please don't let that turn you away from reading it.

**FYI, Android itself is not new to me, however making custom views like this is very new**

I've got a `Custom View` and another `Activity`.  Their relevant code is as follows:

#### Custom View

```
public class SampleView extends View
{
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mX;
    private float[] mPos;

    Painting painting;

    public int value;

    public Path mPath;
    public Paint mPathPaint;

    private static final int DY = 30;
    private static final String TEXTONPATH = "Along a path";

    public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);

        painting = new Painting();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setTextSize(90);
        mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        mPath = new Path();
        //updatePath(value);
        Log.d("LOGTAGGGGG", "" + value);
        makePath(mPath, 620);

        mPathPaint = new Paint();
        mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }


    public SampleView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        painting = new Painting();

    mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setTextSize(90);
    mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

    mPath = new Path();
    Log.d("LOGTAGGGGG", "" + value);
    makePath(mPath, 620);

    mPathPaint = new Paint();
    mPathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPathPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    mPathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public int updatePath(int seekbarProgress)
    {
        Log.d("LOGTAG2", "VALUE: " + value);
        value = seekbarProgress * 6;
        return value;
    }

    public void makePath(Path p, int number)
    {
        p.moveTo(0,0);
        p.cubicTo(0, 0, 0, 0, number,0);    
    }

    public void invalidateCanvas()
    {
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        Paint p = mPaint;

        canvas.drawLine(0, 200, 0, 0, p);
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK); // setting the text color

        canvas.translate(100, DY*2);

        canvas.translate(0, DY*10);

        canvas.translate(100, DY*10);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPathPaint);
        p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(TEXTONPATH, mPath, 0, 0, p);
    }
}
```

#### Activity

```
public class Painting extends Activity
{
    SeekBar curveBar;
    SampleView sampleView;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    int value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_painting);

        curveBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.curveBar);
        sampleView = new SampleView(this);

        curveBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (progress >= 0)
                {
                    value = sampleView.updatePath(progress);
                    Log.d("TESKLJ:TSLKEJT:LESK", "" + value);
                    sampleView.invalidateCanvas();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(Painting.this, "Value: " + curveBar.getProgress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Note: please excuse my logging style and variable naming convention.  they're simply for debugging purposes and ease of use after all**

So, in the `Custom View` function `UpdatePath` (and in the `Activity` the variable value), I'm multiplying the value that I get from the `seekbar` by 6. 
 Both of the `value` variables (in the `Custom View` and `Activity`) are giving the same x6 value when the `seekbar` is moved.

What's supposed to happen is it's supposed to take the x6 value and plug it into the `number` paramter in the `makePath` function.  I'm calling the `makePath` function in both constuctors as you can see.  Currently, if I actually type `value` into the function calls in the constructors (in place of the 620's) the entire drawn canvas disappears and only the `seekbar` remains.

I'm really not sure how to fix this issue and I've been stuck on it for a while.  If someone could help me figure out how to actually make it curve and then give me some insight into if it's possible to keep those settings and move the curved text to another activity, I would truly appreciate it.

Thank you so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: you want to provide `value` in `makePath(mPath, 620);` method from `Constructor` ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf yes that's correct.  but currently if i just replace the 620 with `value` it erases the whole line

Comment: set a default value to 620

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you didn't change anything when you use simpleView's method updatePath. You will get

```
value = seekbarProgress * 6;
```

but when you call invalidateCanvas function. You still draw the same line path on screen.

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
Paint p = mPaint;

canvas.drawLine(0, 200, 0, 0, p);
p.setColor(Color.BLACK); // setting the text color

canvas.translate(100, DY*2);

canvas.translate(0, DY*10);

canvas.translate(100, DY*10);
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPathPaint);
p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
canvas.drawTextOnPath(TEXTONPATH, mPath, 0, 0, p)
```

When you do invalidate, it does truly update the view by calling view's onDraw() method, but you will need to pass the different line path value to it.

Comment: that makes sense.  so you say that I need to pass the different line path value to it.  I was expecting that by changing the value of `value` using `updatePath` and then plugging in that variable into the constructors, it would do exactly what you said.  Should I be doing something different?

Comment: you can do that by calling the `updatePath` method, but you didn't conect the `value` to line path. so, if you connect `value` variable to your `onDraw` function, then I think it would work.

Comment: i understand what you're saying (conceptually) but I've always had an easy time understanding code conceptually.  It's when it comes to coding that I start to get stuck.  So if possible, could you please show me some code as to what you mean by connecting the `value` to the `onDraw`?

Comment: If you just wanna simply make it work, then, when you call `updatePath`, you will be given 6 times value from outside seekbar, then you pass the value into `makePath` function, for example, `makePath(mPath, value)`. After that, when you call `invalidateCanvas`, it should be updated.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incredible late response, I got really sidetracked with other projects I'm doing.  I read your above response and I tried everything I could think of that made sense in relation to what you said, but to no avail.  Is there anything else you can think of that might make it work?

Comment: @MarcKaram would you mind providing that sample project to me? it would be easier if I can get the sample project to start coding instead of doing that from scratch.